# Event subject is missing for recruiting events when use "delta" to get

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

When I use

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarview?startdatetime={today}&enddatetime={next-week}
```

I can get event subject no matter it is one-time or recruiting events.

However, when I use "delta"

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarview/delta?startdatetime={today}&enddatetime={next-week}
```

One-time events have subject while recruiting events do not have subject. Below is one of recruiting events I got:

```
{
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.event",
    "@odata.etag": "W/\"DwAAABYAAACpTc/InBsuTYwTUBb+VIb4AAB0+Esn\"",
    "seriesMasterId": "AAMkADBlZTUwNTkxLWVmODgtNDVhNC1iZjhlLTdjNjA1ODZlMDI5MgBGAAAAAACUbnk-iwQZRbXMgkfKtmYhBwCpTc-InBsuTYwTUBb_VIb4AAAAAAENAACpTc-InBsuTYwTUBb_VIb4AAAUHFHiAAA=",
    "type": "occurrence",
    "start": {
"dateTime": "2017-09-19T05:00:00.0000000",
"timeZone": "UTC"
    },
    "end": {
"dateTime": "2017-09-19T06:00:00.0000000",
"timeZone": "UTC"
    },
    "id": "AAMkADBlZTUwNTkxLWVmODgtNDVhNC1iZjhlLTdjNjA1ODZlMDI5MgFRAAgI1P7xXviAAEYAAAAAlG55P4sEGUW1zIJHyrZmIQcAqU3PyJwbLk2ME1AW-lSG_AAAAAABDQAAqU3PyJwbLk2ME1AW-lSG_AAAFBxR4gAAEA=="
}
```

Is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I see is that using the `/delta` causes me to get each occurrence in the view as a much smaller entity, but I also get the corresponding series master, which has the full details. So in this case, you would get the subject from the master.

So for entities with `"type": "occurrence"`, you would look at the `seriesMasterId`, which should correspond to the `id` of another entity in your response. You can then pull properties like `subject` and `body` from that.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a `expand` way to get "subject" when I use `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarview/delta?startdatetime={today}&enddatetime={next-week}`? Because it is not convenient to request again for each of these recruiting events. "subject" is very basic info.

Comment: You don't need to request again, the master is in the response. You just need to do a little work to find it. No, there's no way to expand it that I know of.